# iTunes library file damaged after manual migration to new Mac

Tags: itunes, time-machine, music, data-transfer, migration

On my old computer, I had the following setup:

1. iTunes Folder containing **iTunes Library.itl** on my main hard disk (~/Music/iTunes)
2. **Music folder** on a second HD where all the actual music files lived (I had checked "Keep library organized").

My new laptop has only one HD, so manually I copied the **Music Folder (2)** to the new HD and put the **iTunes Library.itl**, **iTunes Library Extras** and **iTunes Library Genius** into it (both from a time machine backup).

Opening iTunes brings up a blank library. When I open iTunes by clicking the app icon while holding alt, choose the library it says:

> iTunes library is not valid. iTunes has created a new library and renamed the original to "iTunes library (damaged)".

(translated from German)

I am using Apple Music, too. Am I missing something?

Comment: There's should be another iTunesLibrary.xml which needs to be moved too

Answer (score 1):

As user33958 has pointed out, **iTunes Library.xml** needs to be copied too.